# Ruby ffi struct with value depending from other struct's size

Tags: ruby, ffi

I'm converting a C library with the FFI gem.

One of the structs has one property depending on another struct's size.

```
class MipInterface < FFI::Struct
  layout(
         :state, :uchar,
         :port_handle, :pointer,
         :input_buffer, RingBuffer,
         :input_buffer_bytes, a(MipHeader.size+255+2).u8
  )
end
```

I don't know how to convert the `a(MipHeader.size+255+2).u8` part to something ruby and ffi can understand.

The error is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `a' for MipSdk::MipInterface:Class
```

if I change to:

```
:input_buffer_bytes, MipHeader.size+255+2
```

then I've got this error:

```
TypeError: unable to resolve type '261'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a() is a C function that returns a struct which has a u8 property. That u8 property is probably a type, and if you are lucky it might be something fixed - it looks a lot like a char * buffer, from the name, and because u8 probably means "unsigned 8-bit integer" or `:uchar`

So a 261-byte :uchar array may be suitable (sorry don't know ffi for that)* - depends if MipHeader.size varies on different systems or in config.

I *think* what you want is

```
class MipInterface < FFI::Struct
  layout(
         :state, :uchar,
         :port_handle, :pointer,
         :input_buffer, RingBuffer,
         :input_buffer_bytes, [:uint8, MipHeader.size+255+2]
  )
end
```

I'm also guessing `a(i).foo` is some C convenience wrapper for "declare me an array length i of type 'foo'".